# Paint job estimator rounding up

Tags: python, rounding

I'm suppose to create a program that calculates the cost of doing a paint job. For every 125 square feet of wall space, one gallon of paint an eight hours of labor are required. The company charges $42.50 per hour for labor. The program should ask the user to enter the square feet of wall space to be painted and the price per gallon. The program is to display the following:

- The number of gallons of paint required rounded up to whole gallons
- The hours of labor required
- The cost of the paint based on the round up whole gallons
- The labor charges
- The total cost of the paint job

Negative numbers, zero,  and non-number inputs are not allowed; number of gallons should be rounded up always; a prompt should appear at the end asking for another estimation; hours of labor should be displayed to one decimal paint; gallons of paint should be displayed as an integer value with nothing shown to the right of the decimal; total labor charges should be displayed to two decimal points and a $ is to be displayed at the start of the total charge value.

This is what I have so far:

```
print("This program calculates the cost of doing a paint job.")

do_calculation = True
while (do_calculation):

    while (True):
        try:
            # Input amount of square feet of wall space
            square_feet = float(input("How many square feet of wall space do you need painted? "))
            if (square_feet <= 0):
                print ("Zero and negative numbers can not be accepted.")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("The value you entered is invalid. Only numericals are valid.");
        else:
            break
    while(True):
        try:
            # Input cost per gallon
            cost_per_gallon = float(input("Cost per gallon of paint? $"))
            if (cost_per_gallon <= 0):
                print ('Zero and negative numbers can not be acepted.')
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("The value you entered is invalid. Only numericals are valid.");
        else:
            break
    while(True):
        try:
            # Input number of gallons needed
            gallons_needed = float(square_feet)/125.0
        except ValueError:
            print("The value you entered is invalid. Only numericals are valid.");
        else:
            break


    # Hours of labor expected
    hours_of_labor = 8 * gallons_needed 

    # Cost of Labor expected
    labor_costs = 42.5 * hours_of_labor 

    # Paint cost
    paint_costs = float(cost_per_gallon) * gallons_needed 

    # Number of gallons of paint
    print("The number of gallons of paint required is %f" % gallons_needed) 

    # How long labor lasts
    print("The number of gallons of hours of labor required are %f" % hours_of_labor) 

    # Charged for labor
    print("The labor charges are $%f" % labor_costs)

    # Total amount of labor
    print("Total labor is: %f" % (labor_costs + paint_costs))

    another_calculation = input("\nDo you want to try another estimate? (y/n): ")
    if (another_calculation != "y"):
        do_calculation = False
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I actually have three - all with rounding: How do you have hours_of_labor displayed to one decimal point (ex: 26.5 hours), How do you display gallons_of_paint as an integer value with no decimals (ex: 6), And how do you display the total of labor charges to two decimal points (ex: $144.69)

Answer (score 1):

> I actually have three - all with rounding: How do you have
>   hours_of_labor displayed to one decimal point (ex: 26.5 hours), How do
>   you display gallons_of_paint as an integer value with no decimals (ex:
>   6), And how do you display the total of labor charges to two decimal
>   points (ex: $144.69)

*You should have added these in your actual question*

Formatting of numbers is controlled by adding various [format specifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to the *string* that is output.  Keep in mind that `$144.69` is a string and not a valid number.

You are using some of these already in your code (`%f` is a specifier), you just have to modify these.

Finally - rounding is something you'll have to take care of with respect to the total hours, in this case you'll have to round up (as most contractors in real life do) have a look at the built-in [`round` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) with help on that.

> `gallons_needed = round(float((square_feet)/125.0),1)`? Will this make
>   the input by the user rounded UP always for calculations

You can try it and see:

```
>>> round(1.24, 1)
1.2
>>> round(1.25, 1)
1.3
```

So the answer here is no, it will not always round up. You can read the documentation for more hints on how to make it always round up.

> one minor annoyance: with 'print("The labor charges are:
>   $",(labor_costs))' the program adds an annoying space between the
>   amount and $: 'The labor charges are: $ XXX.XX' How do I get rid of
>   the space between?

Its printing the space because you are passing in *two arguments* to the print function, its just printing one after the other:

```
>>> print('The costs are $',(i))
The costs are $ 144.43
```

If you pass it *one string*, it will print it correctly. Here I am passing in one string, with the argument formatted as a string (`%s`):

```
>>> print('The costs are $%s' % (i))
The costs are $144.43
```

Note here the `()` are unnecessary, (they don't do anything useful). You can omit them:

```
>>> print('The cost are $%s' % i)
The cost are $144.43
```

You can also use the newer string formatting mini-language, like this:

```
>>> print('The costs are ${}'.format(i))
The costs are $144.43
```

Comment: Like: gallons_needed = round(float((square_feet)/125.0),1)? Will this make the input by the user rounded UP always for calculations?

Also, one minor annoyance: 
with 'print("The labor charges are: $",(labor_costs))'
the program adds an annoying space between the amount and $:
'The labor charges are: $ XXX.XX'
How do I get rid of the space between?